# How to save google WEBP image format into database using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webp

I am optimizing a MVC application and obviously for optimization the very first thing is optimize images/pictures. I create webp images with google's webp plugin for photoshop. I am just wondering that is there any possibility to save webp images in a SQL database and display it somewhere in a MVC razor view?

Regards

Comment: you can store files as byte array /var binary in a database. But if it is static content, why you want to do that ? just keep as static file (and do caching) so IIS can server it without executing any mvc request processing pipeline

Comment: @Shyju I do use caching the `OuputCache` one but whenever I check my site performance with google speed test it ask me to optimize the images. Shall I care about it?

Comment: Could they mean the image size? If the size of the displayed images is smaller than actual image (IE the get downsized by the browser) you should provide several images sizes depending on the size of the viewport. This way a mobile user doesn't download 10 of those 2048px product images when 256px images would be enough. I think cloudinary.com provides a service that makes this quite easy.